# After resizing a VDI in virtualbox, Windows 7 guest OS does not see additional space

Tags: virtualbox

After increasing the size of a VDI disk file in virtualbox (using VBoxManage), I found that the guest OS (Windows 7) boots fine, but does not find the additional space.  I have checked disk manager (in the guest) and GParted, but both see the older, smaller HD physical size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed by removing and re-attaching the disk in the virtualbox management GUI.  After that & rebooting the guest into windows, disk manager immediately saw the extra space.

In addition to this, you will have to extent the volume from inside the guest OS, i.e. Windows 7. Go to "Create and format hard disk partitions" in control panel (in guest os - Windows 7). From there select the drive, right click, and in the menu that appears, select "Extend volume". Follow the wizard that appears. Using this I was able to extent the disk space of both the windows boot drive, and an additional virtual drive that I had attached to the guest.